# SIgnalR v2 RC1 CORS request has no cookie using SignalR v2 RC1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain, signalr, cors

Using SignalR V2 RC1
I have a SignalR self-hosted console application that allows CORS connections sitting on Server1 bound to http://*:8080.

On Server2 I have an MVC 4 intranet website that uses Windows Authentication.

When the user first hits the default page via a browser on Server3 the MVC controller assigns a cookie. I would like this cookie to be passed from the browser to the SignalR application on Server1.

When doing this locally via the VS2012 i can clearly see the cookie being set in the browser and subsequently passed to the self-hosted application (running in another instance of VS2012) on each connection.

When done on the servers above, the cookie is no longer sent with the SignalR request.

This problem doesn't seem to be specific to IE9 ( I am aware the IE9 has problems with passing cookies over a CORS connection as per [SignalR IE9 Cross Domain request don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573397/siganlr-ie9-cross-domain-request-dont-work)) as i have also tried this with Firefox with the same result.

I am under the impression from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1735 that the issue regarding CORS and cookies has been resolved for SignalR v2 RC1. So what am i doing wrong?

I have put in a workaround by placing the cookie details into the query string, but i would rather get this working properly by passing the cookies across domain.

For completeness the SignalR self-hosted application is configured as follows, though i'm guessing this really has no bearing on what happens on the client side in terms of sending cookies

```
public class StartupSignalR
 {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableJSONP = true
                };

                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
 }
```

The client side js is as follows

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://10.144.20.150:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //Set the hubs URL for the connection
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://10.144.20.150:8080/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.qs = { 'Token': $.cookie("Token") };
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.myHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
        // Html encode display name and message.
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
        // Add the message to the page.
        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
            + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
    };
    // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
    $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
    // Set initial focus to message input box.
    $('#message').focus();
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start({withCredentials:true}).done(function () {
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub.
            chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are tied to the domain they are originally returned from. The browser will not send a cookie from server1.com in requests to server2.com, even if the page currently served is from server1.com. This is just how cookies work. Putting the information in the querystring is the correct approach here.

Comment: Damian, thanks for that. I thought i was going mad. But i must be fundamentally misunderstanding what CORS is supposed to achieve. I understand the restriction with regards to cookies and Ajax connections to other domains as that's been there since, well pretty much forever. But it was my understanding that CORS is supposed to mitigate that, or specifically https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1735 is supposed to get around the issue of passing the cookies? If that is not the case, i'm a bit confused as to what that github patch fixes.

Comment: CORS is there to allow browsers to make certain requests types from the context of one domain to another that wouldn't usually be allowed. Ajax requests for example are not allowed to other domains by default, unless the browser and server both agree via CORS.